# How to get Puppeteer / Node script to read a <div> by its class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

Is there a way to select a `<div>` by its class in a Node Puppeteer webscraper?

There is a `div` on the web page that looks like this: `<div class="Body-body-qL80Q">`

I want my scraper to grab the text from this `div`. For the time being, I'm just trying to write it to the console to check that it's grabbing the right text.

What is wrong with my `querySelector`? (I previously had the script navigate to the correct page and take a screenshot, which it did correctly, so I know the rest of it works.)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const CREDS = require('./creds');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.squarespace.com/login');

  const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '.username.Input-hxTtdt.ipapEE';
  const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '.password.Input-hxTtdt.ipapEE';
  const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '.Button-kDSBcD.fATVqu';

  await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);

  await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR),
  ]);

  await page.goto('https://triangle-oarfish-hk88.squarespace.com/config/analytics#activity-log');

  const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('Body-body-qL80Q').className);

  console.log(textContent);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

This is the error:

```
(node:6116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null
(node:6116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6116) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a period `.` before the class selector `Body-body-qL80Q` in your [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function inside [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

Also, you should be using the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property instead of the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property.

Your constant `textContent` should be initialized in the following manner:

```
const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.Body-body-qL80Q').textContent);
```

Comment: I made that change, but it just prints the class name to Terminal `Body-body-qL80Q`

Comment: @reallymemorable You should use the `textContent` property instead of the `className` property.